# Play input microphone audio to ausio output

Tags: uwp, microphone, mediacapture

I have a capture card and I ant to display the Video and play the input Sound. I got the video input by using the CaptureElement and MediaCapture

```
Capturemanager = new MediaCapture();

        DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

            device = devices[0];

       

        var mediaInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = device.Id };

        await Capturemanager.InitializeAsync(mediaInitSettings);

        CamCaptureElement.Source = Capturemanager;
        await Capturemanager.StartPreviewAsync();
```

But this does not work for the input microphone. I tried it tis way:

```
            AudioCapturemanager = new MediaCapture();

        DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.AudioCapture);

            audioDevice = devices[0];

        var mediaInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = audioDevice.Id };
        mediaInitSettings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;
        await AudioCapturemanager.InitializeAsync(mediaInitSettings);

        CamCaptureElement.Source = AudioCapturemanager;
        await AudioCapturemanager.StartPreviewAsync();
```

How can I get the audio and play it instantly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When capturing audio, you used VideoDeviceId. You could try to use [AudioDeviceId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacaptureinitializationsettings.audiodeviceid?view=winrt-19041)  instead.

Comment: Thank you! I used AudioGraph. With MediaCapture It did not work.

Comment: You could use the [offical sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation) to do this, which also uses AudioGraph. The Scenario2 captures the audio and generates a file, Scenario2 plays the audio.